# How to add dropdown to an rdl report in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: report, rdl

I need to add a dropdown box to my .rdl report using Visual Studio 2008.

How is this acheived?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is acheived like so...

Add new dataset:

- Right click 'datasets' and add new dataset
- Name it
- Select 'Use a dataset embedded in my report'
- Paste query that returns a single column list into query box
- Click Okay

Add new Parameter:

- Right click Parameters and add new parameter

Set:

- Available values
- Get values from a query

Now:

- Select dataset, value field and label field
- Do the same for default values

Now, alter the main dataset query (right click and edit) to include parameters i.e. @???? where ???? is the name of your dataset.

e.g. For a dataset called 'Name', you might change your query to

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE Name = @Name
```

...and this can be repeated as many times as you like: Preview, save, close and deploy.

EDIT.

If you enable 'allow to select multiple values' then the parameter will be a comma delimited list of values.

For this you'll need a query like:

```
SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(Item)) AS Name INTO #Names FROM dbo.f_split(@Name, ',')

SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE Name IN ( SELECT Name FROM #Names )
```

NOTE:

Create the f_split function with the following:

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[f_split]
(
    @ItemList NVARCHAR(4000), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @IDTable TABLE (Item VARCHAR(100))
AS

BEGIN
    DECLARE @tempItemList NVARCHAR(4000)
    SET @tempItemList = @ItemList

```
DECLARE @i INT    
DECLARE @Item NVARCHAR(4000)

SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)

WHILE (LEN(@tempItemList) > 0)
BEGIN
    IF @i = 0
        SET @Item = @tempItemList
    ELSE
        SET @Item = LEFT(@tempItemList, @i - 1)
    INSERT INTO @IDTable(Item) VALUES(RTRIM(@Item))
    IF @i = 0
        SET @tempItemList = ''
    ELSE
        SET @tempItemList = RIGHT(@tempItemList, LEN(@tempItemList) - @i)
    SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)
END 
RETURN
```

END